# jquery rating-plugin not working in bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using a jQuery rating-plugin (http://wbotelhos.com/raty). If I put it inside a Bootstrap popover, it's not working anymore, no error shown in the console. It just shows the "stars", but there is no functionality.

I tried two different rating-plugins - both not working inside the popover.

The html:

```
<button id="popup_rating" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-trigger="click" data-placement="top" data-title="Rating" class="btn rating">Rating</button>
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" class="hide">
        <div id="star"></div>
</div>
```

The js:

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        ...

        $("#popup_rating").popover({
            content: function() {
              return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
            }
        });  
        $('#star').raty();

    })
</script>
```

Comment: how is the popup loaded and the plugin initiated?

Comment: just updated my quest, sorry to forgot that!

Comment: The problem is that you are returning `$('#popover_content_wrapper').html()` from the `content` which means that a cloned element of `star` is created and for that element the star plugin is not initialized

Comment: Ok, sounds logic. But how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by myself and put everything in the data-content-attribute:

```
<button id="popup_rating"  data-container="body" data-html="true" 
data-trigger="click" data-placement="top" data-title="Rating" class="btn rating" 
data-content="Hallo: <div id='star'></div><script>$(function () { 
$('#star').raty({ path: 'js/' }); } </script>">Rating</button>
```

Not sure if that's the elegant way, but it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

there is easier solution ... just add  .click at the end of popover and call raty like example below ... works like a charm .... also i've added bootstrap slider the same way

```
$('.popover-input-1').popover(
{
  html: true,
  trigger: 'click',
  content: $(".form-input-1").html()
}).click(function(){
//raty star rating  
  $('#star').raty();

//bootstrap slider
  $('#sl1').slider({
    formater: function(value) {
      return 'Current value: '+value;
    }
  });
});
```